# Extracting the Inner Workings of a Decision Tree

Tags: machine-learning, python, interpretation, scikit-learn, cart

I'm training an sklearn decision tree in python, and it has achieved around 99% accuracy on cross validated test data, so I would like to know what exactly the tree is doing in order for it to predict the test data so accurately.

I know I can plot feature importance and look at SHAP values, but I'm wondering whether there is any way I can look at individual nodes on the tree to find out exactly what it's doing?

Answer (score 0):

You could visualize the decision tree using Graphviz

[image]

which [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) shows how to do like this:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, y)
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None, 
                     feature_names=iris.feature_names,  
                     class_names=iris.target_names,  
                     filled=True, rounded=True,  
                     special_characters=True)  
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)  
graph.view()
```

Each node contains the following information:

- decision rule (e.g. $\text{petal length (cm)} \leq 2.45$)
- Gini impurity, $\sum_i p_i (1 - p_i)$
- number of samples that reach the node (e.g. `samples=54`)
- counts of members of each class (e.g. `value = [0,2,4]`)
- dominant (or at least a non-dominated) class (e.g. `class=versicolor`)

And you can also visualize the decision boundary

[image]

which [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_iris_dtc.html) shows us you can do like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.inspection import DecisionBoundaryDisplay

iris = load_iris()


# Parameters
n_classes = 3
plot_colors = "ryb"
plot_step = 0.02


for pairidx, pair in enumerate([[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]):
    # We only take the two corresponding features
    X = iris.data[:, pair]
    y = iris.target

    # Train
    clf = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(X, y)

    # Plot the decision boundary
    ax = plt.subplot(2, 3, pairidx + 1)
    plt.tight_layout(h_pad=0.5, w_pad=0.5, pad=2.5)
    DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator(
        clf,
        X,
        cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu,
        response_method="predict",
        ax=ax,
        xlabel=iris.feature_names[pair[0]],
        ylabel=iris.feature_names[pair[1]],
    )

    # Plot the training points
    for i, color in zip(range(n_classes), plot_colors):
        idx = np.where(y == i)
        plt.scatter(
            X[idx, 0],
            X[idx, 1],
            c=color,
            label=iris.target_names[i],
            cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu,
            edgecolor="black",
            s=15,
        )

plt.suptitle("Decision surface of decision trees trained on pairs of features")
plt.legend(loc="lower right", borderpad=0, handletextpad=0)
_ = plt.axis("tight")
```

The sklearn docs uses standard orthogonal projections above. In principle you can look at other projections which may first involve rotation or other operations.

The former visualization can gives a procedural sense of what a decision tree is doing, and the latter can give you a spatial sense of how the model has partitioned the space.